# C++17 How to mimic Julia's 'promote_type' function using variadic template

Tags: c++, julia, c++17, variadic-functions, type-traits

For some personal reasons, I working on a C++ version of the Julia's `SparseMatrixCSC` that is specific in a project that I port to C++ and where the Armadillo's `SpMat` failed to be a perfect alternative.

```
template <typename Tv, typename Ti>
struct SparseMatrixCSC
{
    size_t m, n;
    arma::Col<Ti> colptr;
    arma::Col<Ti> rowval;
    arma::Col<Tv> nzval;
};
```

Some Julia functions like the `blockdiag()` allow a variadic-like number of sparse matrix in input and one 'blockdiag' matrix in output. The scripting code of Julia allow some generic method that can be ported easily with C++17 like collecting the size of the n-matrix in input, for example :

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr auto blockdiag(const Args& ...args)
{
    auto mX = details::apply([](auto x) { return size(x, 1); }, args...);
    auto nX = details::apply([](auto x) { return size(x, 2); }, args...);
    auto m = sum(mX);
    auto n = sum(nX);
    ...
```

Where the internal `details::apply` function allow to recursively collect the rows/cols on the input n-matrix. The final matrix dimension is summed in `m` and `n`. No problem, the code works perfectly.

But now, my problem is to compute the `typename` parameters of the ouput matrix by collecting/promoting the types `Tv` (value) and `Ti` (indexing) from something similar function. By nature of sparsity matrix, the `Tv` and `Ti` types are numerical values. And more specificaly, `Ti` is an integral type.

As I understand, because i'm a true newbie in metaprogramming with the latest standards of C++, the best way to do that is to use the `<type_traits> std::common_type`. But I don't see how to unpack my variadic template args (that contain the SparseMatrixCSC) and expand the `std::common_type<...>` parameters with the result of the functor that get the decltype of one or another internal column vector `arma::Col<T>`. Something like :

```
template <typename Func, typename ... Args>
constexpr auto promote_type(Func f, Args const&... args)
{
    return typename std::common_type<(f(args), ...)>::type;
}
```

Called in the previous `blockdiag` function by:

```
typename Tv = details::promote_type([](auto x) { return decltype(x.nzval); }, args...);
typename Ti = details::promote_type([](auto x) { return decltype(x.rowval); }, args...);
```

Unfortunately, too bad for the `VS2019 16.5.4` compiler. More, I'm pretty sure that the fold expression `(f(args), ...)` is invalid and cannot be used as template parameter.

So, I need you help, and I thank you very much for that.

EDIT:
To answer Barry, the `promote_type` is a Julia's function described like that :

> Promotion refers to converting values of mixed types to a single
>   common type. `promote_type` represents the default promotion behavior in
>   Julia when operators (usually mathematical) are given arguments of
>   differing types. `promote_type` generally tries to return a type which
>   can at least approximate most values of either input type without
>   excessively widening. Some loss is tolerated; for example,
>   `promote_type(Int64, Float64)` returns `Float64` even though strictly, not
>   all `Int64` values can be represented exactly as `Float64` values.

Comment: Can you describe in more words what it is `promote_type` is supposed to do? It's not clear from the description (maybe with a simple example).

Comment: Dear Barry, I've edit my answer with additional information about the "promotion" concept in Julia. The idea is simple, if I've two SparseMatrix in input, one with floating point value, another with integral value. The prometed type will be floating point. Something similar with common C++ operation like : auto x = 1 + 5.2 where x become 6.2 (a double)

Comment: Okay so `promote_type` in Julia is basically `common_type` in C++. Still don't know what you're trying to do though.

Comment: `promote_type(Int8, Int64)` becomes `std::common_type_t<int8_t, int64_t>`, and is a type.

Comment: Okay. So the blockdiag function get for example two sparse matrix in input (SparseMatrixCSC<Tv,Ti>) but the types are hidden by the variadic template methodology. I need to return a new concatenated (diagonal) sparse matrix where I need to find the correct typename for the new SparseMatrix<Tv,Ti> instanciation. Sorry if my english is poor, not my natural language.

Comment: Oh, each thing in `args...` is some `SparseMatrixCSC<T, U>` and you're trying to figure out the promoted types of the `T`s and `U`s?

Comment: Correct. And `args...` can be an (theorical) unlimited number of `SparseMatrixCSC<Tv,Ti>`. So I need to collect the `Tv` and `Ti` inside the class (struct) by using the specific functor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each of the `args...` here:

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr auto blockdiag(const Args& ...args)
```

is itself a `SparseMatrixCSC`, let's make that more explicit:

```
template <typename... T, typename... U>
constexpr auto blockdiag(const SparseMatrixCSC<T, U>& ...args)
```

This both makes the requirements of `blockdiag` easier to understand (now we know what it takes) and makes it easier to figure out the answer: we have the `T`s and `U`s right there, so just use 'em:

```
template <typename... T, typename... U>
constexpr auto blockdiag(const SparseMatrixCSC<T, U>& ...args)
    -> SpareMatrixCSC<std::common_type_t<T...>, std::common_type_t<U...>>;
```

Comment: Oh yes. Very good answer, but I need to know the `common_type` before returning the `SparseMatrixCSC<Tv,Ti>` because I need to compute the `COO` part of the CSC matrix, the three (column) vector respectively : `colptr`, `rowval` and `nzval`. The three 'arma::Col<>' are template classes. But no problem with your proposition, it's the good way !!! Thank you so much Barry, sincerely !